# GridView CommandName fires on page load

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview, duplicates

I am working on ASP.NET 4.0 . And in which i am using Grid control.And i am binding my grid with Sqldatasource.

My problem is when i perform any operation like Add/Update record then gridview fires its appropriate command by e.CommandName.But after that operation when i load/refresh the page the same e.CommandName fires again.

How we can stop this ?

Below is the code for my RowCommand event for adding new record:-

```
protected void gv_SongDetail_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CommandName == "AddNewSong")
     {
     }
}
```

But after performing that event while i load the page again the e.CommandName value is not changing.It should be empty that time.

Comment: What do you mean by "load the page again" how are you doing this? After a postback if you refresh the page (hit F5) the browser will make the same postback again. So you might want to change the way you do your "refresh".

Comment: yes when i refresh the page.......but it does not matter to me how any body refresh the page.My concern is that the previous CommandName should not be exist at that time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
    }
```